# Ajax POST returning an Bad Request 400

Tags: ajax, post

I have been trying for few hours to debug a Post Ajax call to my server.

I have 2 POST methods: HelloWorld and HelloYou.

Same code, the only difference is that HelloYou takes a string as parameter:

```
namespace WebService
{
    [ServiceContract(Namespace = "")]
    [AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode = AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Allowed)]
    public class Service
    {
        [OperationContract]
        [WebInvoke(Method = "POST",
            BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedRequest,
            ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
            RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
        public string HelloWorld()
        {
            return "Hello World";
        }

        [OperationContract]
        [WebInvoke(Method = "POST",
            BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedRequest,
            ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
            RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
        public string HelloYou(string name)
        {
            return string.Format("Hello {0}",name);
        }
    }
}
```

The HTML client looks like that:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>My Application</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/Scripts/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"</script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/Scripts/ajax.js"> </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/Scripts/events.js"> </script>
</head>
<body>
    <button id="world">HelloWorld</button>
    <button id="you">HelloYou</button>
</body>
</html>
```

and the Ajax calls:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#world').click(function () {
        HelloWorld();
    });

    $('#you').click(function () {
        HelloYou();
    });
});

baseAddress = "http://localhost:53016/Service.svc/ajax/";

function GetURL(method) {
    return baseAddress + method;
}

function HelloWorld() {
    $.ajax({
            async: false,
            url: GetURL("HelloWorld"),
            dataType: 'json',
            type: 'POST',
            data: null ,
            processdata: true,
            contentType: "application/json;charset-uf8"
        })

        .done(function(data) {
            alert(data.d);
        })
        .fail(function (xhr, status, errorThrown) {
            alert(status + errorThrown);
        });
}

function HelloYou() {
    $.ajax({
        async: false,
        url: GetURL("HelloYou"),
        dataType: 'json',
        type: 'POST',
        data: JSON.stringify('{"name": "Chris"}'),
        processdata: true,
        contentType: "application/json;charset-uf8"
    })
    .done(function (data) {
        alert(data.d);
    })
        .fail(function (xhr, status, errorThrown) {
        alert(status + errorThrown);
    });
}
```

I have tried few different ways to pass the parameter to the Ajax call:

```
data: JSON.stringify('{"name": "Chris"}'),
data: '{"name": "Chris"}',
data: '{name: "Chris"}',

var name ="Chris"
data: '{name: ' + JSON.stringify(name) + '}',
```

Every time, I get an error Bad Request 400. The same function HelloWorld with no parameter works fine.

I am lost.

I checked with Fidler the HTML Request/Response:

POST /Service.svc/ajax/HelloYou HTTP/1.1

HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request

Thanks all

Isidore

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to make it work. I changed the method from POST to GET.

For the data, I looked on JQuery API Documentation:

```
    data: { name: "John"},
```

and it works. I am surprised, I thought GET wouldn't let me push data to the server.

Cheers

Isidore